# OrientDB force property type to be string

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I'm using OrientDB and trying to create new property after I inserted my data (millions of rows).

I'm trying to create property on V in order to create an index and I'm getting the following error:

> The database contains some schema-less data in the property
>   'V.ACCOUNT_NO' that is not compatible with the type STRING. Fix those
>   records and change the schema again [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]

Now part of the fields type is INTEGER but it seems to me that it's very easy to convert the type to STRING.
 how can I do it to the entire data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your case by creating this simple structure in schema-less mode:

[image]

These records are a mix of `INTEGER` and `STRING` types:

[image]

Now you can convert the not string records type by using this query:

```
UPDATE V SET ACCOUNT_NO = ACCOUNT_NO.asString() WHERE ACCOUNT_NO.type() <> 'STRING'
```

**Output:**

[image]

About the exception, I got correctly the same error when I try to create a new property `V.ACCOUNT_NO` of type `STRING` in schema-full mode and this is correct because the property already exists in the database and contains mixed types of records, although in schema-less mode.

Once all the records were converted, you'll able to create the new property.

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, did you have a chance to try my solution ?

Comment: Hi, did you verify if my solution works correctly in your case ?